# Android API 30 is not shown though I installed the SDK

Tags: android

I have installed the API 30 SDK in Android Studio:

[image]

In my project code, when I try to specify the target level to 30, the pop up list only shows me API 29 as the latest API level, why is that?

[image]

My root level build.gradle:

[image]

My app level build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: There should be option "R" on top , else try writing R directly and see what happens .

Comment: Have you tried to "Invalidate cache and restart"?

Comment: Yes I tried invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compileSdkVersion` in your module's `build.gradle` file might be set to `29`. If so, raise it to `30`.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the build.gradle, I have 30 there specified.

Comment: @user842225: By default, those `build.gradle` lines are not going to be used. They declare some `ext` values; those would still need to be applied somewhere. Make sure that your `compileSdkVersion` value there is getting applied to the module where your Java file resides.

Comment: Thanks but how can I "Make sure that your compileSdkVersion value there is getting applied" when it doesn't apply?

Comment: @user842225: Your third screenshot would appear to be from your project-level `build.gradle` file. That is not where `compileSdkVersion` gets configured for your module. The module's `build.gradle` file is where `compileSdkVersion` gets configured for your module. Check your module's `build.gradle` file and confirm that your `compileSdkVersion` is 30 or higher.

Comment: It is a top level build.gradle file. You can also see it from the 3rd screenshot, it has a comment as well.

Comment: @user842225: That is **not** where `compileSdkVersion` gets configured **for your module**. The module's `build.gradle` file is where `compileSdkVersion` gets configured for your module. Check your **module's** `build.gradle` file and confirm that your `compileSdkVersion` is 30 or higher.

Comment: My app module build.gralde has configured `compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion` which refers to the root build.gradle `ext{...}` block that is showing in my question code snippet. So, the compileSdkVersion is 30

Comment: I updated my OP with a screenshot of app module build.gradle to indicate.